# Using Rally SDK2 seems to have trouble with opening a new window/tab with a _blank tag

Tags: javascript, rally

If I create a custom HTML page in Rally with straight HTML and a link to a story to open in another window, clicking the link takes me to the details page of the story properly. But if I wrap the same HTML in the SDK2, I get sent to an almost blank page -- only the dark blue top bit of the Rally page shows.

This works:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a target="_blank"
href="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/9805917202ud/detail/userstory/10746587690">US35</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0p5/sdk.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Rally.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('CustomApp', {
          extend: 'Rally.app.App',
          componentCls: 'app',
          launch: function() {
            this.add({
              xtype: 'container',
              html: '<a target="_blank" href="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/9805917202ud/detail/userstory/10746587690">US35</a>'
            });
          }
        });
        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
          name: 'test'
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      .app {
        /* Add app styles here */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  </html>
```

Any ideas out there?

Comment: This is due to a bug in Rally. Thanks for bringing it up, we will get this fixed soon.

Comment: Any update on this Matt? It doesn't appear to have been fixed in RC1...

Comment: This has now been fixed and will go out two releases from now (should be next week at the latest). Apologies for taking so long! We are now putting some checks in place to ensure a defect like this doesn't take so long next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: fixed in Rally as of 8/22/2013! Should work for all versions of AppSDK 2.0.

Still a bug in Rally, caused by the link opener being an iframe.

As a work around you can have an onclick open the window from the main window.

`<a href="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/9805917202ud/detail/userstory/10746587690" onclick="window.top.open(this.href); return false;">US35</a>`